# How to convert list of decimals to a list of hexadicimal with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, hex, decimal, converters

actually I want to convert a list of decimal to a list of hexadicimal. I tried **.toRadixString(16)** But I got : **The method 'toRadixString' isn't defined for the type 'List'.**.
this is my code:

```
  BehaviorSubject<List<int>> _value;
  Stream<List<int>> get value => Rx.merge([
        _value.stream,
        _onValueChangedStream,
      ]);

  List<int> get lastValue => _value.value ?? [];
 Future<Null> write(List<int> value, {bool withoutResponse = false}) async {
    final type = withoutResponse
        ? CharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse
        : CharacteristicWriteType.withResponse;
    var request = protos.WriteCharacteristicRequest.create()
      ..remoteId = deviceId.toString()
      ..characteristicUuid = uuid.toString()
      ..serviceUuid = serviceUuid.toString()
      ..writeType =
          protos.WriteCharacteristicRequest_WriteType.valueOf(type.index)!
      ..value = value.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16)).toList();

    // Uint8List(4)..buffer.asInt32List()[0]=value;

    //..value = value.toRadixString(16);
```

I would be very thankful if you can give me a solution for converting this list from decimal or int to hexadicimal.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVOkQ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdIod.png)

Comment: Convert all the decimals in list to hexa decimal in for loop or for each method.

Comment: see https://pub.dev/documentation/convert/latest/convert/hex-constant.html

Comment: @SuganDev ```List<int> _getRandomBytes() {

    List data = [
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XAB,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XAB,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XAB,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XAB,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XAB
    ];
    data.forEach((value) {
      var c = value.toRadixString(16);
      return c;
    });
  }```  I tried this but I got The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'List<int>

Comment: But the radixString returns String right?

Comment: The whole error is hidden in new screen shot. Scroll donw in the pop up for error. Error will be in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use toRadixString on list.

as on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/toRadixString.html:

> Converts [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int-class.html) to a string representation in the given radix.

as in documentation you should use toRadixString on int.

in your case you can try this:

```
  List get hexLastValue => _value.value.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16)).toList();
```